# What is the use of this capacitor compared to the other near it?

Tags: microcontroller, pcb

It is a lock PCB circuit and I can't understand why it's parallel to the 12 V and ground (the capacitor I circled), but the other capacitor (C539) is like a maintaining contact for 24 V.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Follow the connections through the relay and look at the different states of the relay ....

Comment: I did . And created a schematic diagram . Thats why i cant understand why the 2 capacitors are not of the same design . For example if you follow the 24v line . Then capacitor is parallel with 1 and 5 on relay . But in 12 volts its parallel on (p912) line 1 and 2

Answer (score 2):

This DPDT relay has a Cap. on each pole to the nearest supply rail to act as a partial snubber for an inductive load when released to absorb yet resonate the reactive high voltage.  These are preferably polycarbonate or polyester metal film caps with low ESR and high voltage ratings.  They can also serve to remove oxidation on contacts somewhat over time with one current surge rather than contact bounce with more arcing.

Comment: So it means that the capacitor(c539) acts as partial snubber for 24v and the capacitor(c540) is the partial snubber for 12v supply ?

Comment: No but all supply DC voltages are ideally treated the same for AC characteristics +24V and Gnd while 12V is isolated